# What does the following mean as a type: () => void = null

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at these two function declarations:

```
function f1(chainFn: (fn: Function) => void = null) {

}

function f2(): (...args: any[]) => (cls: any) => any {

}
```

I don't really understand what the following parts define:

```
// function that accepts `fn` of Function type by returns what?
(fn: Function) => void = null

// function that accepts an array of arguments and returns a function that returns a result of `any` type?
(...args: any[]) => (cls: any) => any
```

Can anyone please elaborate and possible provide examples of concrete implementations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first function `f1` accepts an argument `chainFn` and it is a function that as a parameter accepts a function `fn` and does not return anything `=> void`, also this parameter `chainFn` is optional `= null` with runtime default value of undefined.

The second function `f2` does not accept any arguments and returns a function. That function accepts open parameters list of any type `...args:any[]` (you can call it using comma separated arguments `var r = f2(); r(1,2,3,4);`) and it returns a function that accepts any type as parameters and returns something.

Comment: thanks, so this `f1(chainFn: (fn: Function) => void = null)` can be logically grouped like this `f1(chainFn: ((fn: Function) => void) = null)`, correct?

Answer (score 12):

```
() => void
```

Is the type of a function which takes no arguments and does not return anything.

```
() => void = null
```

Is not a type at all.

```
function f(g: () => void = null) { ... }
```

Is a function `f` which takes another function, `g` of type `() => void`, as an argument and provides a default value of `null` for that argument if it is not provided. This also renders the argument optional.

I would like to add that using `null` as the default value of an optional argument is a terrible practice because JavaScript passes `undefined` not `null` for unspecified arguments and there's no reason to change this behaviour as doing so is surprising. In such a case it is preferable to either write

```
// g is optional and will be undefined if not provided
f(g?: () => void) { ... }
```

or to write

```
// g is optional and will be a no-op if not provided.
f(g: () => void = () => {}) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks, re _is a terrible practice_ - the code I've shown is from angular2 source code, not sure why they used `null`, but thanks for bringing it up

Comment: The angular2 code base is full of code that you should not emulate. I'm sorry but this is a fact. For example it contains `interface Type<T extends Function> extends Function {}`. Which is borderline blasphemous ;). What I mean is that it is confusing as all hell to have a type named Type it actually means that it has an associated value of the same name at runtime.

Comment: The angular team says people will not use this type in userland but I see it all the time and it is stupid. It encourages people to conflate very different things

Comment: I see, thanks again for pointing that out. Indeed, the TS sources are really hard to read. GL)